# how to add tab character into test string section of regex101.com

Tags: regex

I am using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to learn regex.

There will be cases where I want to insert a <kbd>Tab</kbd> character within the TEST STRING field of regex101.com.

However, when I have the TEST STRING field selected and press the tab key on my keyboard, it doesn't enter the tab character within the TEST STRING field, but rather it just moves me on to the next selectable feature within the browser page.

I note I have done a bit of googling but so far haven't been able to find the answer to how to add a tab character within the TEST STRING field. Although I know for sure it is possible to do this given that I have seen a few videos where the presenter successfully adds a tab character into the field.

I note that I am using Windows 10 and my browser is Google Chrome.

Would greatly appreciate if anyone could provide an answer to this.

Comment: Notepad => TAB => ctrl+C => ctrl+V ?

Comment: pretty annoying, but you can use regex replace to create tabs: https://regex101.com/r/PyJR4V/1

Comment: It's even harder when using a phone: I setup a text replacement on my iPhone so when I type "tab" the text `-> <-` is typed out instead (the arrows are included so I can find the tab char). I entered the tab originally by highlighting text that contained a tab and trimmed it.

Comment: Tell regex101 to implement equivalent DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DLGC_WANTARROWS  |  DLGC_WANTCHARS | DLGC_WANTMESSAGE | DLGC_WANTTAB in their OnGetDlgCode handler for their editor control. Its just and editor, should be able to control what keys it wants

Answer (score 5):

Appears regex101 can enable the tab key to be translated by the editors
instead of being pass-through to the system where it changes focus to the
next control in the tab order.

Just uncheck the box in Settings .

[image]

Apparently preference gets saved in your browser session cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Typing a <kbd>Tab</kbd> into a text editor and copy-pasting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>) it into the browser form is an easy solution. Just make sure your editor is not configured to auto-replace tabs with spaces.

Another way would be using a keyboard combination to enter the ASCII or Unicode character code (see [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/111165/1210682)). For [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0), that should be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+  <kbd>0</kbd>  + <kbd>9</kbd> (Note: apparently the numbers need to be entered on the numpad).

Finally, depending on the browser you use, there might be browser extensions that facilitate what you want. There used to be one called [Tabinta](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/firefox/addon/tabinta/) for Firefox and one for Chrome called [chrome-textarea-formatter](https://code.google.com/archive/p/chrome-textarea-formatter/), but I  believe neither of them is still maintained.

Comment: Linux: Ctrl + Shift + u, then 09, then Enter.

Comment: Windows: ALT+09   (09 on the numeric keyboard)